# Default error icon is not displayed for EditText setError

Tags: java, android

I have a validation on the EditText in my Android app. The Error message pops up as expected but the default error icon is not displayed.

[image]

```
    if(users.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
        errorNum++;
        users.setError("Field can not be empty");
    } else {
        users.setError(null);
    }
```

I also tried with the custom icon, it doesn't work too.

```
users.setError("Field can not be empty",getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_error_outline_black_24dp));
```

How to get the default error icon for validation

LAYOUT file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.dinesh.note.MainActivity">

<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"> 

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:labelFor="@+id/users"
            android:text="@string/users"
android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Widget.TextView" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/users"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="number"
             />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:labelFor="@+id/years"
            android:text="@string/years"


android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Widget.TextView" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/years"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"


            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="number" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:labelFor="@+id/percentage"
            android:text="@string/percentage"
            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Widget.TextView" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/percentage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:labelFor="@+id/months"
            android:text="@string/months"
            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Widget.TextView" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/months"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="number" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tamount"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/calculate"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:text="@string/tamount"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/amount"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tamount"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:text="@string/amount"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Large"
    android:textSize="36sp"
    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/calculate"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:text="@string/calculate"
    android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
    android:layout_marginTop="227dp"
    android:onClick="calculateBtn"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

styles xml

```
<resources>
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

</resources>
```

Comment: Can you post your layout file?

Comment: added my layout file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would seriously suggest you consider the modern approach to this kind of thing for one reason: with more users upgrading their devices, backwards compatible libraries from Google are already available to do this.

For instance, try : `TextInputLayout` which is available through the support library. If you have not added already, do this in your `app-level build.gradle` file.

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.0'
```

Then in your layout file:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/quoteIdWrapper"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:gravity="start"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/quoteId"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:lines="8"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:gravity="top|start"
        android:minLines="5"
        android:maxLines="10"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:inputType="textCapSentences|textMultiLine"
        android:hint="@string/quote_text"/>

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

From your code, you can then get references to both items (`TextInputLayout & EditText`).

Next, validate the Edittext field and if something is invalid, set the following attributes to the `TextInputLayout` reference:

```
textInputLayout.setErrorEnabled(true);
textInputLayout.setError("Your error message");
```

This will automatically signal with the right color (red often) to the user making it easier to know that something is a miss.

I hope you get my idea. Good luck!!

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways-

**Method 1**

You can create your own class of `EditText` by overriding `setError()` method and use`setCompoundDrawables()` method to display error icon.

```
public class CustomErrorEditText extends EditText {

    public CustomErrorEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public void setError(CharSequence error, Drawable icon) {
        setCompoundDrawables(null, null, icon, null);
    }
}
```

**Method 2**

You need to set the bounds on the drawable before using it in `setError`.

```
Drawable drawable = getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_error_outline_black_24dp);
drawable.setBounds(0, 0, drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawable.getIntrinsicHeight());
users.setError("error", drawable);
```

Comment: `setError(String)` will give you default icon